# How to assign value of a variable inside jquery $.get() callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ajax

I am begginer. In my code `validStatus` is a variable. Which i returned at end of function. this `validStatus` is not set to true/ false value inside jquery $get() callback function. how can i set variable and return that variable.

```
function isOpeningyearValid(openingyear) {
    //openingyear is valid . when it is First Fiscal year
    var validStatus;
    var url = "/Inventory/InventoryOpeningStock/isOpeningyearValid?openingyear=" + openingyear;
    $.get(url, function (res) {
        if(res.validStatus == true)
        {
            successNotify("yes first fiscal year");
            validStatus = true;
        }
        else {
            errorNotify("not first fiscal year");
            validStatus = false;
        }
    });
    console.log("validation status",validStatus);
    return validStatus;
}
```

please note that: errorNotify(); and successNotify(); is executing according to the `if(res.validStatus == true)`. but only `validStatus` is not set to any value. i think its a variable scope problem.

Comment: Because of deferred execution the return will usually run **before** the call is finished. You're better off creating a global variable and setting that to true or false (like you are currently) and not having the function return anything.

Comment: Also see [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: @MathewThompson that is incorrect. The `return` will **in all cases** return before the `$.get()` callback runs. And a global variable won't really help (always) as the rest of the code won't know when the value is eventually set.

Comment: @Pointy fair, I did actually write all originally but retracted to usually incase someone came back with a curveball case lol.

Comment: @Pointy you are right global is not working